# sbt launcher stack overflow (Version 1.*)

Tags: scala, sbt, launcher

I want to use `sbt-launcher` to get *SBT*, and run it. I have following `sbt.boot.properties`:

```
[scala]
  version: ${sbt.scala.version-auto}

[app]
  org: ${sbt.organization-org.scala-sbt}
  name: sbt
  version: ${sbt.version-read(sbt.version)[1.3.7]}
  class: ${sbt.main.class-sbt.xMain}
  components: xsbti,extra
  cross-versioned: ${sbt.cross.versioned-false}
  resources: ${sbt.extraClasspath-}

[repositories]
  local
  maven-central: http://artifactory.corp.com/artifactory/joined-maven-releases
  typesafe-ivy-releases: http://artifactory.corp.com/artifactory/joined-ivy-releases, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]

[boot]
  directory: ${sbt.boot.directory-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/boot/}

[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${user.home}/.ivy2/}
  checksums: ${sbt.checksums-sha1,md5}
  override-build-repos: ${sbt.override.build.repos-false}
  repository-config: ${sbt.repository.config-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/repositories}
```

If I set SBT vertions to `0.13.18`, it works fine: `version: ${sbt.version-read(sbt.version)[0.13.18]}`, however with the latest version I am getting stackOverflow error:

```
[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.3.7  (this may take some time)...
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.XMLHelper.getDocBuilder(XMLHelper.java:213)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.XMLHelper.parseToDom(XMLHelper.java:207)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomReader.<init>(PomReader.java:95)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:122)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:112)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.ModuleDescriptorProvider.provideModule$6172736d(ModuleDescriptorProvider.java:716)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.getStale(ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.java:68)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.cacheModuleDescriptor(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:1195)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.parse(BasicResolver.java:536)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:271)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.getDependency(IBiblioResolver.java:538)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.getDependency(ChainResolver.java:104)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseOtherPom(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:382)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:112)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.ModuleDescriptorProvider.provideModule$6172736d(ModuleDescriptorProvider.java:716)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.getStale(ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.java:68)
```

Why exactly this happens, how can I debug it the best way ?
When I am trying to fetch SBT 1.3.7 using maven, it works fine, so it is available in the repo.

I am starting `sbt-launcher` like this:

```
set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
java -Xmx8G -Xss2G -jar "%SCRIPT_DIR%launcher-1.1.3.jar" %*
```

**Addition:**

I find out that the last version it works with is 1.2.3, when I change it to 1.2.4 then it produces the following stack trace indefinetly untill StackOverflow error pops up:

```
at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.parse(BasicResolver.java:536)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:271)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.getDependency(IBiblioResolver.java:538)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.getDependency(ChainResolver.java:104)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseOtherPom(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:382)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:112)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.ModuleDescriptorProvider.provideModule$6172736d(ModuleDescriptorProvider.java:716)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.getStale(ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.java:68)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.cacheModuleDescriptor(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:1195)
```

Comment: do you have the same problem with sbt `1.2.8`?

Comment: yes, only 0.* versions works fine

Comment: Can it be that jvm need more RAM

Comment: can you try `sbt -mem 3000`

Comment: where do I put these settings ?

Comment: A 2GB stack is ridiculous. What happens if you remove the `-Xss` option from you command? Maybe Java (or the launcher) misinterprets the `G` somehow?

Comment: it produces the same result

Comment: I wonder if this can be related to artifactory setup ? The strange thing is that if I add sbt 1.* as a dependency in maven project it can fetch it without problems

Comment: try to enable debug output of the launcher: add `[log]\n  level: debug` to your properties file.

Comment: BTW, is this the full stack trace?

Comment: @cbley, its a full stack trace, but it repeats many times. Btw the last version it works fine with is 1.2.3, when I change it to 1.2.4 it blows up.

Comment: did the debug output give any clue?